# string to dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, text-parsing, information-extraction

I have a string that I want to transform into a dictionary, the string looks like this:

```js
const str = '::student{name="this is the name" age="21" faculty="some faculty"}'
```

I want to transform that string into a dictionary that looks like this:

```js
const dic = {
  "name": "this is the name",
  "age": "21",
  "faculty": "some faculty"
}
```

So the string is formated in this was `::name{parameters...}` and can have any parameters, not only `name`, `faculty`, ... How can I format any string that looks like that and transform it into a dictionary?

Also Is there a way to check that the current string I'm parsing follow this structure `::name{parameters...}`, that way I can throw an error when it does not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show any research you've done into the issue and any attempts you've made based on that research.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem: how did you end up with the string at the first place? Is there no way to ensure that the information/data is sent over in a format that is compatible with most languages (read: JSON)?

Comment: Have you defined the syntax to parse? E.G. How are single and/or double quotes included in the string?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only have alphanumeric and spaces or an empty string within the parentheses of the values, and there is never a space between the key and value in `key="value"` you can match with the following **regular expression** and then iterate over it to construct your desired object.

```js
const str = '::student{name="this is the name" age="21" faculty="some faculty"}'
const matches = str.match(/[\w]+\=\"[\w\s]*(?=")/g)
const result = {}
matches.forEach(match => {
  const [key, value] = match.split('="')
  result[key] = value
})
console.log(result)
```

The regex is composed of the following parts:

[image]

You can use https://regexr.com to experiment with your regular expressions. Depending on the string to process, you'll need to refine your regex.

Answer (score 1):

This example uses [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to look for matches in the string using a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```js
const str = '::student{name="this is the name" age="21" faculty="some faculty"}';

const regex = /([a-z]+)="([a-z0-9 ?]+)"/g;

let match, output = {};

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
  output[match[1]] = match[2];
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

If not exist a unique pattern, it is hard, but when pattern is the same, you can split the string:

```
  var str  = '::student{name="this is the name" age="21" faculty="some faculty"}'

  console.log(createObj(str));


  function createObj(myString){
    if(myString.search("::") !== 0 && myString.search("{}") === -1 && myString.search("}") === -1){
      console.log("format error")
      return null;
    }

    var a = myString.split("{")[1];
    var c = a.replace('{','').replace('}','');
    if(c.search('= ""') !== -1){
      console.log("format incorrect");
      return null;
    }

    var d = c.split('="')

    var keyValue = [];
    for(item of d){
      var e = item.split('" ')
      if(e.length === 1){
        keyValue.push(e[0].replace('"',''));
      }else{
        for(item2 of e){
          keyValue.push(item2.replace('"',''));
        }
      }
    }

    var myObj = {}
    if(keyValue.length % 2 === 0){
      for(var i = 0; i<keyValue.length; i=i+2){
        myObj[keyValue[i]] = keyValue[i+1]
      }
    }
    return myObj;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 patterns. The first pattern to match the format of the string and capture the content between the curly braces in a single capture group. The second pattern to get the key value pairs using 2 capture groups.

For the full match you can use

```
::\w+{([^{}]*)}
```

- `::\w+` match `::` and 1+ word characters
- `{` Match the opening curly
- `([^{}]*)` Capture **group 1**, match from opening till closing curly
- `}` Match the closing curly

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8dXlDV/1)

For the keys and values you can use

```
(\w+)="([^"]+)"
```

- `(\w+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word chars
- `="` Match literally
- `([^"]+)` Capture **group 2**, match from an opening till closing double quote
- `"` Match closing double quote

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b8tZtU/1)

```js
const str = '::student{name="this is the name" age="21" faculty="some faculty"}';
const regexFullMatch = /::\w+{([^{}]*)}/;
const regexKeyValue = /(\w+)="([^"]+)"/g;
const m = str.match(regexFullMatch);

if (m) {
  dic = Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(m[1].matchAll(regexKeyValue), v => [v[1], v[2]])
  );
  console.log(dic)
}
```